# Yo @microsoft/sharepoint generator Cannot find "package.json" file required by this generator

Tags: spfx, yeoman-generator, yo

I just reset my development environment and installed node and npm via nvm. Also installed yeoman and downloaded the @microsoft/sharepoint generator. When I go to run the yo @microsoft/sharepoint I get to to the point where I name my extension and get the following error:
Error

Cannot find "package.json" file required by this generator

Comment: have you ever found a solution ? thx

Comment: I'm sorry it's been so long I don't recall how I fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

This happens if you already have a .yo-rc.json file in the folder you're trying to create your SPFx project OR the file exists in a folder higher up the tree.
It might be that you can't see it because this file could be hidden.

This was what was in the folder I was running the yo command in.

[image]

Deleting the files fixed it for me.